# Else return for returning to originals state is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My code for changing the background color works great, but the "else" return does not work.  Am I missing something?  here is what i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("test");

  input.onclick = function ()
  {
    document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";

    else {
      document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
      document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#000";

    }  
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. FWIW, the most useful thing I learnt when I started programmiong was learning to check with simple test cases. If you come across something like this again, try to make a minimal test case eg - `if(document.getElementById("q_i").style.backgroundColor = "#000"){alert('yes');}else{alert('no');}.`

you should take care not to leave any alerts() in production code unless they're intentional but they can be very handy for easy debugging. Also, check the JS errors in your browser - they often give an explanation of what the problem was (although it can be cryptic - then google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the "if" part of the statement...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var input = document.getElementById("test");

 input.onclick = function ()
 {

    if(SOME_CONDITION) {
 document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";

    } else {
 document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
 document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#000";

 }



 };});
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you... Can the some condition be as simple as the existing background color?

Comment: @Erik: A condition must evaluate to a boolean value. What is your intention with the `else` clause? What is the purpose of the code? If you just do `if("#AAB3AA")`, it will always evaluate to `true`. I *guess* that you want `if(document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor == '#000')` to toggle the colors.

Comment: I want to want to change the background color of the input and a div when clicked and returned when clicked outside.

Comment: I went ahead with your suggestion:

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var input = document.getElementById("test");

 input.onclick = function ()
 {

    if(document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor == '#AEB7AD') {
 document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";

    } else {
 document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AEB7AD";
 document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AEB7AD";

 }



 };});
 </script>

Comment: Still won;t return to its original state

Comment: That's because you're only "doing something" when the user clicks on the desired item, not when they "blur" (click away from) the desired item. Really all you need to do is have 2 events, onclick and onblur. In one of them you set one colour, in the other you return to the origional colour.

Comment: I'm confused do combine the two together or separate functions?

Comment: No good...


$(document).ready(function() {
var input = document.getElementById("test");

input.onblur = function ()
{
    document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AEB7AD";
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AEB7AD";
   
};});

$(document).ready(function() {
var input = document.getElementById("test");

input.onclick = function ()
{
    document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";
    
    
};});
</script>

Comment: Thanks Felix for your help.  I figured it out!!!  many thanks:

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#test").focus(function () {
  jQuery(this).addClass("highLightInput");
  jQuery("#quote_input").addClass("highLightInput"); 
 });
 jQuery("#test").blur(function () {
  jQuery(this).removeClass("highLightInput");
  jQuery("#quote_input").removeClass("highLightInput");
 });
});
</script>

Answer (score 5):

Well sir, unless I'm mistaken, you are missing an [IF statement](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_if_else.asp).